# Upload folder security solutions

Tags: php, security, upload, chmod

We all know that chmod 777 is not the best way of making our upload script to work. So i was thinking what would be the best solution when using it.

I thought that when the user uploads a file "**picture.jpg**", i could rename it to "**md5(username-picture-1.jpg)**" and to show it on the webpage as `<img src="files.php?img=username-picture-1.jpg">`.

Then on this files.php file would look like

```
<?php
    $file = md5($_GET['img']);

    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    echo file_get_contents($file);
?>
```

That way the user wouldn't know the filename of the file he has uploaded, that said, he wouldn't be able to execute it. Am i right?

And obvisouly i would have some other checkings to handle the upload like mime type and other stuff. I just want to know if this would be a way to prevent the user to execute the file he uploaded.

Comment: It's a way of making it annoying to work out what file was requested. But most code is open source, so you can't rely on security by obscurity. 

There is another reason people like Facebook don't do this. You have transformed your website to 1 PHP execution per page to 1 per image (+1 for a page). On a gallery that might be 30x the traffic.

You shouldn't need `chmod 777` anyway, the file should be executable by only the user that the webserver runs as (which should not be root).

Comment: How could that be done? I don't have ssh access!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add an .htaccess file to the Folder which contains the uploaded files to prevent execution, but I think it's a better way to check the mime-type/file-extension of the uploaded file before you store them permanently on the file system

Comment: Did you mean something like <Files ^(*.jpeg|*.jpg)> order deny allow deny from all</Files> ?

Comment: No - you want to prevent the access to the complete Directory - so you have to place i.e. an .htaccess file in you /upload folder with `deny from all` as it's content

Comment: By doing that i would still be able to show the images on the page with <img src="..."> ?

Comment: if you use your src="file.php?.." solution - yes

Comment: LFI attacks are still problematic.

Comment: I'm using a md5($_GET['img']), would it still be problematic?